# Grails test-app consumes too much cpu?

Tags: grails

I have a grails 2.4.4 app and I'm running tests on my local machine. 
An Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 480 @ 2.67GHz × 4 , with 8GB memory with ubuntu 12.04 as my OS. 
I run around 1000+ tests and when the tests almost finish, my machine shuts down and I have to start all over again. It just consumes too much memory. I even try to run the tests without anything on other than a terminal, and immediately it shoots up to 100%.  :(

Comment: So there's a bug in your app.

Comment: run tests one by one, within some profiling tool probably, it could help you with finding issue